# ActiveMerchant PayPal Express possible bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, activemerchant

I am a little bit confused, somehow I am able to change the amount of the purchase:

First I setup my purchase,

```
@setup_response = gateway.setup_purchase(
  10*100,
  :ip                => request.remote_ip,
  :return_url        => url_for(:controller => "payments", :action => 'confirm', :only_path => false),
  :cancel_return_url => url_for(:controller => "payments", :action => 'error', :only_path => false),
  :currency => 'EUR',
  :email => current_user.email,
  :no_shipping => true,
  :items => items
)
```

Later I do the purchase:

```
  purchase = gateway.purchase(
      500*100,
      :ip       => request.remote_ip,
      :payer_id => params[:payer_id],
      :token    => params[:token],
      :currency => 'EUR'
      )
```

As you can see I have changed the amount from 10 -> setup/user agreed to 1000 when purchasing and it did work in the Paypal Sandbox.

I think this is really strange. Can anybody confirm this? This should not happen?
Is this perhaps only possible in the Sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure Paypal Express Checkout does not require the amount at `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` (which is what `setup_purchase` maps to) to be the same as that at `SetExpressCheckout`.  To quote [Paypal's documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted):

> In the simplest case, you set the total amount of the order when you
>   call the SetExpressCheckout API. However, you can change the amount
>   before calling the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API if you did not know
>   the total amount when you called the SetExpressCheckout API.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed some leeway between the set-up and the purchase - this is to allow people changing their order, discounts, etc.

Don't take the risk of billing people more than you clearly state - Paypal are very quick to give people refunds so you'll end up losing out in the long run.

Comment: This I won't do! I was just a little bit confused it seemed to me like giving a blank cheque away.